# Why does transforming from equatorial coordinates to galactic coordinates require 3 equations?

Tags: astronomy, coordinate-systems

My question seems self explanatory but still:

In transforming equatorial coordinates to galactic coordinates or the reverse you have to solve a well known system that has three equations.

Since there are only 2 variables (the coordinates) shouldn't the system be completely determined by 2 of those equations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not always a system of n equations with n variables have a single solution. Not even a linear system. Same with the transformation between the two coordinates. Put for instance $\alpha=0$ and $\delta=90$. Solving only two of the equations leaves the quadrant of $l$ indeterminate.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the 3 eqs. are not independent. You can check, with a little patience, that if you square and add them you get the identity $1=1$. This is because the eqs. are nothing but the transformation (rotation) for cartesian coordinates of one point of a sphere with radius $r=1$ from one system of axes to another.

Of course to single out a point on the sphere two (polar) coordinates are enough, and you could easily find expressions of $\alpha$, $\delta$ as functions of $l$, $b$ or vice versa. Unfortunately inverse trigonometrical functions are required, which cannot be uniquely extended to the whole trigonometric circle. Then formulae thus obtained must be used with caution, as errors are lurking.